# Finding x in Ax = B in matlab

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab

I am trying to solve for $x$ in $Ax = B$ in matlab as well as attempting to understand the actual process behind solving a linear equation of said form. My vectors are A and B and they look like this

$ A = \left[\begin{matrix}
    0 & -1 & 1 \\
    3 & 17 & -11 \\
    3 & 17 & -11 \\
    1 & 7 & -5
    \end{matrix} \right]
$

$ B = \left[\begin{matrix}
    -1 \\
    16 \\
    17 \\
    7
    \end{matrix} \right]
$

Now my reasoning is that $A$ is a matrix of size $4x3$ and $B$ is of form $4x1$, then $x$ must be of form $3x1$ because $A$ can only be multiplied with a vector with four rows and $B$ has only one column. The equation turns plays out like this
$$
 Ax = \left[\begin{matrix}
    0 & -1 & 1 \\
    3 & 17 & -11 \\
    3 & 17 & -11 \\
    1 & 7 & -5
    \end{matrix} \right] \times \left[\begin{matrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{matrix} \right] = 
\left[\begin{matrix}-y + z \\ 3x +17y -11z \\ 3x + 17y -11z \\ x + 7y -5z \end{matrix} \right] = \left[\begin{matrix}
    -1 \\
    16 \\
    17 \\
    7
    \end{matrix} \right]
$$

that means that we have four equations and three unknowns. Equation two and three contradict each other (resulting in 0 = 1 from equation 3 when -1*equation 2 + equation 3). Therefore the equation is unsolvable.

$$
-y + z = -1 \\
3x +17y -11z = 16\\
3x +17y -11z = 17\\
x + 7y -5z = 7\\
$$

Matlab, however says that B\A = x, and $$x = 0.1782, 1.026, -0.6706$$ I got this way of solving the equation from [mathworks](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html). Where am I going wrong? Is the equation $Ax = B$ in my case solvable?

Comment: `A \ b` will minimize $\|Ax-b\|_2$ if the system is overdetermined, as in this case.

Comment: As @DavidKraemer stated, when the system is overdetermined, the `\` operator will minimize the residual, in a least-squares sense, ie, it will find the `x` vector that minimizes the norm of the residual `Ax-b`.  check that `norm(Ax-b)` will be the smallest value for the `x` provided, and any other `x` you may come up with, will give a higher norm for the residual.